# Chatter REST Batch Post Multiple Files: Missing expected "fileData" binary parameter

Tags: apex, rest-api, chatter

### Batch Post Files

I'm trying to use the Chatter REST API to batch post multiple binary files using the `/connect/batch` resource.

According to the last example in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_batch.htm), I've put together the below sample code which you can run from the Developer Console (make sure to add your instance's URL to Remote Site Settings to allow the callout).

### Sample Code

```
String header = '--some_random_boundary_string' + '\r\n';
String separator = '\r\n' + '--some_random_boundary_string' + '\r\n';
String footer = '\r\n' + '\r\n' + '--some_random_boundary_string--';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint( URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v39.0/connect/batch');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=some_random_boundary_string');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setBody(header +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/json' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
            '{ "haltOnError" : true, "batchRequests" : [' +
                '{ "url": "/v39.0/connect/files/users/me", "method":"POST", "binaryPartName":"binaryPart1", "binaryPartNameAlias":"fileData" },' +
                '{ "url": "/v39.0/connect/files/users/me", "method":"POST", "binaryPartName":"binaryPart2", "binaryPartNameAlias":"fileData" }' +
            ']}' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
            separator +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart1"; filename="FileA.txt"' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' + '\r\n'  + '\r\n' +
            'aaa' + // content for FileA
            separator +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="binaryPart2"; filename="FileB.txt"' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' + '\r\n'  + '\r\n' +
            'bbb' + // content for FileB
            footer
);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setTimeout(60000);

HttpResponse res = new Http().send( req );

System.debug( res );
System.debug( res.getBody() );
```

### Error Response

However, I get back an error response message "Missing expected 'fileData' binary parameter". I'm confused because as far as I can tell, I've specified **fileData** in the **binaryPartNameAlias** JSON field.

```
00:24:24:198 USER_DEBUG [35]|DEBUG|System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]
00:24:24:198 USER_DEBUG [36]|DEBUG|{"hasErrors":true,"results":[{"result":[{"errorCode":"POST_BODY_PARSE_ERROR","message":"Missing expected &quot;fileData&quot; binary parameter"}],"statusCode":400},{"result":[{"errorCode":"BATCH_PROCESSING_HALTED","message":"Batch processing halted per request"}],"statusCode":412}]}
```

### What does work, posting single file using different resource

I have been successful at posting a **single** file if I use the `/connect/files/users/me` resource instead, but then I'm making a REST request per file I want to upload.

```
String header = '--some_random_boundary_string' + '\r\n';
String separator = '\r\n' + '--some_random_boundary_string' + '\r\n';
String footer = '\r\n' + '\r\n' + '--some_random_boundary_string--';

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint( URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v39.0/connect/files/users/me');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=some_random_boundary_string');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.setBody(header +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileData"; filename="FileA.txt"' + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1' + '\r\n' + '\r\n' +
            'aaa' +
            footer
);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setTimeout(60000);

HttpResponse res = new Http().send( req );

System.debug( res );
System.debug( res.getBody() );
```

Comment: I work at Salesforce and your code looks correct to me (I wouldn't expect to get an error). I've created an internal ticket for the team to investigate further. If you end up creating a support ticket, please reference work item  W-3807787.